# Form submit button does not work immediately after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit, parsley.js

I'm using Parsley validation with my Bootstrap formatted form.
The problem is that when the page is loaded, submit button does not do anything for a while. The delay varies but sometimes as long as 10 seconds!

The code is running on local server using wamp-server.
I tried both Opera and Firefox browsers

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // On submit
  $('#form_register').submit(function(e) {

    console.log('Form submitted!');

    // Prevent normal submittion
    e.preventDefault();

    // Validate
    if ($(this).parsley().isValid()) {

      // gather data
      var data = $('#form_register').serialize();

      // send data to server
      $.post('http://127.0.0.1/part/register/ajax_register', data, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        // If success
        if (data.code == 0) {

          // Show success emssage
          modal_message('ثبت نام با موفقیت انجام شد', 'success', function(event) {
            // Redirect to login page
            window.location = "http://127.0.0.1/part//login";
          });
        } else {

          // Show error message
          modal_message(data.message, 'danger');
        }
      }, "json");
    } else {
      console.log('Not validated');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container my-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
      <div class="card border-primary shadow">
        <div class="card-header bg-primary text-white">
          فرم ثبت نام
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form id="form_register" method="post" data-parsley-validate="">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="username">نام کاربری :</label>
                  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" required data-parsley-required-message="نام کاربری را وارد کنید">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="company">شرکت :</label>
                  <select name="company_id" id="company" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">پارت پلاستیک</option>
                    <option value="2">قطعات محور</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password">کلمه عبور :</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" required pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" data-parsley-required-message="کلمه عبور را وارد کنید" data-parsley-pattern-message="کلمه عبور باید حداقل ۸ حرف و شامل حروف بزرگ، کوچک و یک رقم یا کاراکتر خاص باشد.">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="repassword">تکرار کلمه عبور :</label>
                  <input type="password" name="repassword" id="repassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" data-parsley-equalto="#password" data-parsley-equalto-message="هر دو کلمه عبور باید یکسان باشند">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="first_name">نام :</label>
                  <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" autocomplete="name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="last_name">نام خانوادگی :</label>
                  <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control" autocomplete="family-name">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="mobile_number">تلفن همراه :</label>
                  <input type="text" name="mobile_number" id="mobile_number" class="form-control" autocomplete="mobile" pattern="^09\d{9}$" data-parsley-pattern-message="شماره تلفن همراه اشتباه است">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="phone_number">تلفن ثابت :</label>
                  <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" class="form-control" autocomplete="tel" pattern="^\d{8,12}$" data-parsley-pattern-message="شماره تلفن اشتباه است">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="address">آدرس پستی :</label>
                  <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-control" autocomplete="street-address">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="date_birth">تاریخ تولد :</label>
                  <input type="text" name="date_birth" id="date_birth" class="form-control" autocomplete="bday" placeholder="0000-00-00" pattern="^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$" data-parsley-pattern-message="فرمت تاریخ تولد اشتباه است" value="1985/01/01">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" value="ثبت نام" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The delay is because you have placed form  submit code inside $(document).ready(function(){})

So the form submit code will execute once the complete dom is displayed.

If you don’t want to wait till the DOM loads. Then place the form submit code outside document.ready function.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(....)` says that to run all functions inside it after all DOM elements loading. Just use outside of it you you need. And if u have few more values to be passed, just use ajax, it will overcome this problem too.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "http://127.0.0.1/part/register/ajax_register", 
    data : {'data':data },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache : false,
    async:true, //asynchronous,No need to wait for the response
    success : function(data) {  
        //your statements
    },
    error : function(data) {
        //your statements
    }
})
```